# C - Loop to "plant mines" in a 2D Array Minesweeper doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, codeblocks, minesweeper

I've been tasked to create a simple Minesweeper-clone for a C/C++ class. It requires some use of a 10x10 char 2D array as the minefield.

I will need to place 5 mines randomly on the field. Empty spots should be filled with a space (' '), while spots with mines are to be filled with a hash ('#').

Here's the code to create the 2D array. The array was declared outside (above) the main() function, but was initialized inside the main() function:

```
...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

static char minefield[10][10];

main(){

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++){
        for (int colm = 0; colm < 10; colm++){
            minefield[row][colm] = ' ';
        }
    }
...
```

With this, I declared the array and filled all the spaces with spaces. I have some code to print out the array, and it seems to hold other characters. *However, I cannot tell if this code does fill the array with spaces or with something else like null.*

***Next up, the part where I believe the problem lies: Planting the mines.*** The mines are to be placed in five random locations across the array, which is handled by a for loop. The loop also checks if the space is occupied, and will continue to loop until five mines are successfully placed.

```
...  
    srand(time(0)); //Defining seed for random

    int randRow;
    int randColm;

    for (int count = 0; count < 5;){
        randRow = rand() % 10;
        randColm = rand() % 10;
        if (minefield[randRow][randColm] != ' '){ //tests if space is occupied
            continue;
        }
        minefield[randRow][randColm] = '#'; //planting the mine
        count++;
    }
...
```

With some debugging, I found that the code seems to halt/hang in

```
minefield[randRow][randColm] = '#';
```

At this point, the program just terminates and prints an execution time of a few seconds.

My IDE doesn't seem to report any errors (I'm using Codeblocks).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you presented is fine. The error is somewhere else. It's better to `int main()` then just `main()`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Consider running under valgrind. It will flag many memory access errors, hopefully giving you some hints on how to proceed. Alternatively, just step thru the code. with gdb.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk It seems that changing int main() doesn't solve a thing. 
However, I did find something new! I tried running the program several times, and when the loop tried checking minefield[0][0] and assigning '#', the it didn't hang! Something is still off and I cannot tell what's wrong...

Comment: @MikeCAT There isn't anything else beside debugging code that I've written outside what was mentioned here. As a result, giving the entire code might be very messy and a little unhelpful.

Comment: Then what you think is going to be helpful? Others can't guess your code. [The code you showed, works.](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SubduedUnusualLivecd) Remove all the unnecessery and unnedded parts of your code until you are left with the smallest compilable code example that is needed to reproduce the problem. Then post it here. `program just terminates` What did you expect the program to do? Right now the code you showed doesn't have any printing statements. Did you use a debugger to step line by line the execution of your program?

Comment: So... I actually put the "rest of my code" in there that link you sent, Kamil... and it does work. Like, I practically put in the rest of my code into that link you shared with me, and it does work! So what's going on? Could this be a problem with my IDE or Compiler?

Comment: EDIT: Kamil, I am sorry that I did not give you the entirety of the code. It turns out that I misused a puts() function, where I put in a variable, thinking it worked like print in Java. I erased the statement and did try using a printf() and it works! This is all thanks to that link you gave me... "repl.it"? It seemed to show exactly where my code went wrong. Might you know how I can use such a feature in an IDE like Codeblocks? Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note:

I've made a mistake in the code which was unshown. I put a variable directly in a puts() function (e.g. puts(variable)) instead of using printf (e.g. printf("%c", variable)) which caused the program to hang.

It wasn't until I was shown a site called repl.it, which had a debugger that showed me what was wrong.

Sorry if this inconvenienced anyone. But thank you for helping me eitherway!

P.S. Might anyone know how I can have this feature in my Codeblocks IDE? This debugging was included when I used the Eclipse IDE for Java, but not in Codeblocks for some reason. I have little experience in using IDEs.